Different result for same url using http request client like axios, fetch, superagent
I have used different http request client with this url: "https://skynet.certik.com/quest/daily-task" but got different results. (you can try below code in nodejs)
Using Axios:

const axios = require('axios');

const url = "https://skynet.certik.com/quest/daily-task";

async function requestSwapHemi() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

// Usage example
async function main() {
    try {
        const response = await requestSwapHemi();
        console.log('Response:', response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

main();

Using node native fetch:
const url = "https://skynet.certik.com/quest/daily-task";
async function requestClient() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET"
        });
        const data = await response.text(); // Use .text() if expecting HTML/text
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Usage example
async function main() {
    try {
        const result = await requestClient();
        console.log('Response:', result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch:', error);
    }
}

main();

For node native fetch, the response is OK and show right html returns, but for Axios, it return 403 status and show below response, I also tried other library like got, node-fetch, superagent, all return the block response.

All the request send in same ip and network without any vpn or proxy.
I know there must be something relative with the cloudflare validation, but why the native fetch works only. How can i change the config to make other library work?

You can compare the headers they send. Native fetch at least differs with user-agent. You can only guess how their antibot protection works. I get 403 with any of these methods including native node fetch but not in a browser, so it's potentially not reproducible
